# Jquery datepicker as popup?

Tags: jquery, html

I am very new to jquery and only basic experience with javascript.

I would like an html input that when clicked would make the JQuery datepicker popup, which would fill in the html input.
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

Can someone give me an example on how to accomplish this or give me a link that will point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: You have the right link already, click the "view source" button down below or try this link and again look for the "view source" button. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started

Comment: u r asking as jquery ui dialog popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jQuery UI datapicker.   It is very use to add and very easy for a user to use.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Create it in a div, and then pop it, this is the easiest way.

```
<div id="datepickerholder" style="display: none;">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>
<a id="pop">pop datepicker</a>
```

and the JS

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#pop").click(function(){
        $("#datepickerholder").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

You can also create the instance after the click, which means, there's no hidden container
another JS, but still works

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<a id="pop">pop datepicker</a>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#pop").click(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
```